# Product of two non-principal ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

> I have problems understanding why 
>   $$(6,2+\sqrt{-56})(6,-2+\sqrt{-56})=6(2,\sqrt{-56})$$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-14}]$.

By definition the product of two ideals $$IJ=\sum_{i,j}^{k}f_{i}g_{j}$$

we have

$(6)(6)=36$

$6(2+\sqrt{-56})=12+6\sqrt{-56}$

$6(2-\sqrt{-56})=12-6\sqrt{-56}$

$(2+\sqrt{-56})(-2+\sqrt{-56})=-60$

so $6$ divides all the products hence $IJ\subseteq (6)$

How to find other inclusion? Could someone explain why the product equals $6(2,\sqrt{-56})$

Thank you.

Comment: As ideals of which ring? $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-14}]$?

Comment: Note that the factor $6$ says that the product ideal is within $(6)$, but the ideal you are looking for does not contain any odd multiples of $6$.

Comment: What is $6(2, \sqrt{-56})$? is it $(12,6\sqrt{-56} )$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, yes sorry, it was my mistake. They both belong to this ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-14}]$

Comment: @MarkBennet, Thank you. Good point. I have not thought about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide by $6$, then in your ideal you have 
$$6, 2+\sqrt{-56}, 2-\sqrt{-56}, -10$$

so you also have $-10+ 2\cdot 6=2$. And then you get $\sqrt{-56}$

so you contain $(2,\sqrt{-56})$. The other direction is then clear.

Comment: Thank you Rene. Do I get it right: We have to show that $(6, 2+\sqrt{-56}, 2-\sqrt{-56},-10)=6(2,\sqrt{-56})$?

Comment: Yes you want to show the equality of those two ideals, (but you forgot the $6$ factor on the irrationals).